# Rebuild Index script issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to run the following script, I get some errors due to collation for some databases.

Error message:

> Msg 451, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in add operator occurring in SELECT statement column 1.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
> A cursor with the name 'TableCursor' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
> A cursor with the name 'TableCursor' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
> A cursor with the name 'TableCursor' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
> A cursor with the name 'TableCursor' does not exist.

Script used:

```
DECLARE @Database text   
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(255)  
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000)  

DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
    SELECT name 
    FROM master.sys.databases   
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master','msdb','tempdb','model','distribution')  -- databases to exclude
--WHERE name IN ('DB1', 'DB2') -- use this to select specific databases and comment out line above
      AND state = 0 -- database is online
      AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log  shipping
    ORDER BY 1  

OPEN DatabaseCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @cmd = 'DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT ''['' + table_catalog + ''].['' + table_schema + ''].['' +  
   table_name + '']'' as tableName FROM [' + @Database + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE'''   

    -- create table cursor  
    EXEC (@cmd)  
    OPEN TableCursor   

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY   
            SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD' 
            --PRINT @cmd -- uncomment if you want to see commands
            EXEC (@cmd) 
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT '---'
            PRINT @cmd
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
            PRINT '---'
        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
    END   

    CLOSE TableCursor   
    DEALLOCATE TableCursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
END  

CLOSE DatabaseCursor   
DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor
```

Comment: Why are you [re-inventing the wheel?](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "collation conflict" occurs when you add strings with a different collation.  For example:

```
select 'a' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + 
       'b' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC
-->
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the add operation
```

You query information from each database's INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  That may be a different collation from the collation of your script.  You can query the collation for each database with:

```
select name, collation_name from sys.databases
```

When you create a variable it takes the default collation for the active database context.  You could cast to that collation while adding strings:

```
SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' +
           @Table COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + ' REBUILD'
```

How does this option work for you?